# Failed while publishing clickonce application

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce

I get the following error while trying to publish a wpf clickonce application.

Error
1
Publish failed with the following error: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.DTEClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The error happens if I try to publish to an FTP site and also if I try and publish to the local file systems.

Any ideas? Googling doesn't seem to produce any useful results.

Comment: 1) No, didn't try by HTTP. I don't think my hosting company has this option. 2) No COM. It's a vanilla WPF app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EnvDTE.DTEClass is some functionality that should be provided by Visual Studio. I have a few suggestions:

1. Create a new WinForms project (just
   an empty Form) and try to publish
   that.
2. Try Repairing or Reinstalling VS
3. Have a lookt at [Building ClickOnce
   Applications from the Command
   Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Option 2 is probably the problem. I'll have to investigate that.
Option 3 would be good to try too. MAGE shouldn't spit out EnvDTE errors, so it might work from the command line. I need to learn MSBuild anyway, so...

Comment: Option 1 didn't work.
Option 3 worked!
I'm going to retry option 2 and see if that helps. Such a pain though.

Comment: had a similar problem and just got it to work from the command line (3) on my new development machine. Hurray! Now I don't have to abandon my users and I can publish bug fixes without having to boot up my old dev machine.

Answer (score 1):

This EXACT error was solved in my case by just running the following command:

```
regsvr32  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

or for 32bit windows:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

More info:
The issue turned out to be broken registration for IServiceProvider. The proxy-stub CLSID was wrong (it was referring to actxprxy.dll instead of ieproxy.dll on Windows 7 x64).

Extracted from: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2012/10/02/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-microsoft-visualstudio-ole-interop-iserviceprovider.aspx